# C++ How to bind arguments to a function which accepts a function?

Tags: c++, bind

I have a function `fx_1` which accepts a function and other arguments. I want to create a new function `f1` whose arguments are some of `fx_1`. However I can't use `f1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

double fun_exp(double x, double* y) {
    return exp(x) - x - 1;
};
double fx_1(function<double(double, double*)> fun,
    double x0, double* data = nullptr, int order = 4) {
    return 5.0;
};

int main() {

    auto f1 = bind(fx_1, fun_exp, _2, _3, 4);
    double* x = new double;
    *x = 6.0;
    cout << f1(3.0, x) << endl; //Compile Error

    function<double(double, double*)> f2 = bind(fx_1, fun_exp, _2, _3, 4); //Error.

    function<double(double, double*)> f3 = bind<double,
        function<double(function<double(double, double*)> fun, double, double*, int)>,
        double, double*>(fx_1, fun_exp, _2, _3, 4); //Error.

}
```

I thought that `f1` should accept arguments of type `double, double*` because types of arguments 2 and 3 of `fx_1` are `double, double *`.

In `f2` and `f3`, I tried to explicitly set template arguments however they both doesn't work.

Comment: You are using `_2` and `_3`, so the result is a function that takes three arguments.

Comment: Please be more specific than "Error" and "doesn't work". Copy and paste your error messages into the question.

Comment: Don't touch `bind` with a six foot pole. Use a lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placeholder numbering refers to the arguments in future calls of the bound function.
That is, `bind(fx_1, fun_exp, _2, _3, 4);` is a function(-like) that takes three arguments and only uses the second and third, such as `f1(0, 3.0, x)`.

(If they referred to the function you're binding, you wouldn't need any numbering.)

Use `_1` and `_2` or (more readable and no less efficient) a lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

bind() 's placeholders represent args passed to the created new function, so your '_2, _3' should be '_1, _2'